# miceforest imputation based on groupby on big data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, imputation

Imagine having a similar database, but a huge one with millions of rows and millions of names.

```
data = {'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
        'job': ['teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer','teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer'],
        'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
        'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
        'meal_price': [8, 11, 27, 19, 7, 10],
        'date': ['6-12-2022', '6-12-2022', '6-12-2022','6-13-2022', '6-13-2022', '6-13-2022']
        }
```

I need to run miceforest on the database to fill out missing values, but need to do that based on values on column "names", meaning need to do sth similar to groupby and then run the imputation.
Appreciate your help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) df

    |name   |job        |age|weight |meal_price |date
|---|-------|-----------|---|-------|---|--------
|0  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |160    |8  |6-12-2022
|1  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |209    |11 |6-12-2022
|2  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |130    |27 |6-12-2022
|3  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |164    |19 |6-13-2022
|4  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |206    |7  |6-13-2022
|5  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |132    |10 |6-13-2022
|6  |Alex   |teacher    |NaN|NaN    |NaN|6-14-2022
|7  |Ben    |doctor     |NaN|NaN    |NaN|6-14-2022
|8  |Marry  |engineer   |NaN|NaN    |NaN|6-14-2022
```

Comment: How would you do it for one name?

Comment: that's my question. I wanted to do the imputation based on the names, for example, when the model wants to do the imputation, put higher priority on data for "Alex". Is that possible? or does the model already consider that? Of course I need to do encoding first, and then run the model; in that case it will change Alex to 0 here, would it possibly put information for alex around same location and consider data from him as closer to the missing value (closer k values)?